# Throwing IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#

I'm fairly new to C#, and for some reason I'm being thrown an IndexOutOfRangeException for a substring with the bounds of 0 and 0.

I don't think it's an issue with my scope as I've tested to make sure everything is defined where it is used.

I'm trying to make a very simple anagram generator:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string[] d = { "Apple", "Bass", "Cat", "Dog", "Ear", "Flamingo", "Gear", "Hat", "Infidel", "Jackrabbit", "Kangaroo", "Lathargic", "Monkey", "Nude", "Ozzymandis", "Python", "Queen", "Rat", "Sarcastic", "Tungston", "Urine", "Virginia", "Wool", "Xylophone", "Yo-yo", "Zebra", " "};
        string var;
        int len = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var = textBox2.Text;
            //textBox1.Text = d[2];
            for (int y = 0; y <= var.Length; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x <= d.Length; x++)
                {
                    if (d[x].Substring(0, 0).ToUpper() == var.Substring(len, len).ToUpper())
                    {
                        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "\n" + d[x];
                        len = len + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Array index ranges from 0.. len-1

Comment: I guess you should try **d[x].Substring(0, 1)** instead.

Comment: Just for the reference, i would refrain from using var as a variable name as it can also be used as an implicite type such as var myString = "Hello"

Comment: Your code also doesnt handle an empty string in the `var` variable.

Answer (score 1):

The upper bound of a zero-based array (or a zero-based indexed string) is one less the length.

```
for (int y = 0; y < var.Length; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < d.Length; x++)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to read past the end of an array in two places:

```
for (int y = 0; y <= var.Length; y++)  // here (var is a string which is an array of char)
{
    for (int x = 0; x <= d.Length; x++) // and here
```

Arrays use a zero-based index. Therefore the last element is at index position [Length-1].

When you try to access the element at position [Length], you get the IndexOutOfRangeException. This position is one element past the end.

Don't allow your loop counter to exceed Length-1:

```
for (int y = 0; y < var.Length; y++)  
{                 
    for (int x = 0; x < d.Length; x++)
```

Answer (score 0):

In *zero*-based indexing, you can't index on the end point, as that would be out of range. For length 10, you have go to iterate from 0-9:

```
for (int y = 0; y < var.Length; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < d.Length; x++)
    {
        if (d[x].Substring(0, 0).ToUpper() == var.Substring(len, len).ToUpper())
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "\n" + d[x];
            len = len + 1;
        }
    }
}
```